# JavaMonkey Canvas

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas

I've been trying to get Java monkey engine-3 to render to a canvas/panel object so it can be embedded in a GUI. I'm sure this must be possible but searching around every program i can find just extends the simpleapplication class.

Any advice on how to do this? Even just a link to some good examples or documentation would be nice. I don't really need anything as powerful as Java monkey to render out a few cubes spheres and the like in 3D so if anyone wants to suggest a more appropriate, simpler alternative that would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial in their documentation: http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:swing_canvas

Comment: Thanks mate, sorry for late reply. I had given up hope :P